# Can I push to the same branch of a repository on github from two different locations?

Tags: git

I just started using Git and Github 2 weeks ago, and I wonder if it works the same way clouds do; by pushing to the same branch of the same repository from 2 different locations (2 computer, same files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoever pushes second will have to do a `git pull` first and resolve any merge conflicts that occur before being able to push their changes to the remote repository. This is because they need to know about what others have changed before pushing their own on top of them.

Since you're new to Git, I recommend reading some [Git tutorials](http://git-scm.com/documentation), as Git is a very complex tool with many commands. It is immensely more frustrating to use if you don't understand how it works.

Comment: so basically I just perform the exact same steps that I already did on the first computer (initiation, adding files, defining remote repo... etc.) with no change of sequence other than cloning, then pulling before doing any pushing... Am I correct?

Comment: Erm, no. That wasn't part of your original question either. You shouldn't be creating a new repository again, as there already is one; you only need to do a clone after the repository has been created for the first time to get a copy of it.

Comment: OK, so after I clone the repo, how do I push new commits to the same remote repo?

Answer (score 1):

I generally tend to do a rebase, so that the branch changes are clean

http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html

I also have a copy of a cheat on my wall, this helps a lot

http://help.github.com/git-cheat-sheets/

Comment: The cheat sheet is interesting but a bit confusing, thanks anyway.